# How to hibernate laptop when it overheats

Tags: hibernate, overheating, bios

I was wondering If I could set the same behavior as windows 7 do in the laptop when it overheats, it hibernates. Hibernation (from ubuntu) works fine, after I re-enabled it. Would it be possible to make the laptop hibernate whenever it overheated while running on ubuntu ? If yes, How will it be done?
Some days are hot and the laptop sometimes gave in to it sometimes.

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and the laptop is Compaq Presario CQ42-357TU.

Comment: So what does Ubuntu do when it overheats for you? I always see kernel messages first if it comes close to the critical temperature @Braiam mentions, and the moment it hits it, the kernel will initiate an emergency shutdown.

Comment: A better question would be why is it overheating in the first place?  You should fix/replace your broken hardware if it is overheating.

Comment: @psusi Broken hardware is not the only possible cause of overheating. Driver problems can cause it. And there are other causes too, like poor ventilation (such as vents being blocked), dust accumulation, and high ambient temperature (which makes cooling harder, though of course it won't directly cause overheating).

Comment: @EliahKagan, blocked vents falls under hardware, and drivers can't do it either; the hardware is designed to not overheat no matter what software does.  Modern CPUs even slow themselves down to prevent overheating in the face of some dust or other minor problems.

Comment: @psusi To an extent this comes down to using words differently, so I'm not sure I disagree with anything you're saying. But a blocked vent or dust accumulation is not *broken* hardware. Also, remember that a CPU is not the only part of a computer that generates heat; often, it is not even the most significant one. (GPUs, and occasionally other components like hard disks, can generate more.)

Answer (score 2):

Normally, OS do an Emergency Shutdown whenever the die reach a certain temperature which in [your case](http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz) is 90°C.

Windows and Ubuntu (any Linux distribution) has different ways to deal with overheating, so it's not necessary that Ubuntu (any Linux distribution) respond the same to overheating.

I don't know how to change this behavior, you should ask another question for this. And it is also preoccupying that your Laptop overheats, maybe you should check for dust on the fan and air flow, if that doesn't help you should check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85830/41104) about how to diagnostic weird cases.